# Get values from metatada.txt

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is there a built in function in PyQGIS to import the values from a plugin's `metadata.txt`?

I am developing a plugin and want to show the `version` corresponding to the value from `metadata.txt`. Is there a native way to get the values or would I have to parse the file by myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No native way by my knowledge. Last time I used the fine code with a ConfigParser from Dockable MirrorMap plugin by Faunalia for an aboutbox.

```
import ConfigParser
import os
import platform

try:
    import resources
except ImportError:
    import resources_rc

class DlgAbout(QDialog, Ui_DlgAbout):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'metadata.txt'))

        name        = config.get('general', 'name')
        description = config.get('general', 'description')
        version     = config.get('general', 'version')

        self.logo.setPixmap( QPixmap( ":/faunalia/logo" ) )
        self.title.setText( name )
        self.description.setText( description )

        text = self.txt.toHtml()
        text = text.replace( "$PLUGIN_NAME$", name )

        subject = "Help: %s" % name
        body = """\n\n
--------
Plugin name: %s
Plugin version: %s
Python version: %s
Platform: %s - %s
--------
""" % ( name, version, platform.python_version(), platform.system(), platform.version() )

        mail = QUrl( "mailto:abc@abc.com" )
        mail.addQueryItem( "subject", subject )
        mail.addQueryItem( "body", body )

        text = text.replace( "$MAIL_SUBJECT$", unicode(mail.encodedQueryItemValue( "subject" )) )
        text = text.replace( "$MAIL_BODY$", unicode(mail.encodedQueryItemValue( "body" )) )

        self.txt.setHtml(text)
```